# only half Sphere drawing

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to draw a sphere, I am a starter in OpenGL, I was following a site and trying to convert things according to my needs, but it draws even less than half of the sphere. The code that I have written is

```
for(unsigned int stackNumber = 0; stackNumber <= stacks; ++stackNumber)
{
    for (unsigned int sliceNumber = 0; sliceNumber < slices; ++sliceNumber)
    {
        float theta = stackNumber * PI / stacks;
        float phi = sliceNumber * 2 * PI / slices;
        float sinTheta = std::sin(theta);
        float sinPhi = std::sin(phi);
        float cosTheta = std::cos(theta);
        float cosPhi = std::cos(phi);
        vertex.xyzw[0] = radius * cosPhi * sinTheta;
        vertex.xyzw[1] = radius * sinPhi * sinTheta;
        vertex.xyzw[2] = radius * cosTheta;
        //vertex.xyzw[3] = 0.0f;

        vertices.push_back(vertex);
    }
}
int n = 0;
//int x = stacks*(slices + 1)*2;

//index = new GLuint[x];

for (unsigned int stackNumber = 0; stackNumber < stacks; ++stackNumber)
{   
    for (unsigned int sliceNumber = 0; sliceNumber <= slices; ++sliceNumber)
    {
        index.push_back((stackNumber * slices) + (sliceNumber % slices));
        index.push_back(((stackNumber + 1) * slices) + (sliceNumber % slices));
    }
}
```

but it only draws half of the sphere, but when I run the code made by the tutor, it draws full sphere, what should I add to this so that it makes the complete sphere.

Currently I am not using GL Depth test or anything like projection, view etc. Trying to keep it as simple as possible as I am just a starter. Want to go step by step incrementally adding everything. I am drawing elements till index.size() in glDrawElements.

Also I would like to mention I am using TRIANGLE_STRIP

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (char*)NULL + 0);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, index.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (char*)NULL + 0);
```

This is what I am getting
[image]

Comment: Compare your code to your tutor's code, and examine the differences....

Comment: what is your vertex datastructure (3 or 4 elements)?

Comment: you could be hitting a buffer size limit - if that is the case reducing stacks and/or slices should result in more of the sphere being drawn

Comment: Yes I was hitting the buffer limit. Thanks,